# PyGame window crashes during while loop - no error message

Tags: python, crash, pygame

```py
import pygame, sys, time, os
from scripts import UltraColor
from scripts import textures

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 1280
displayHeight = 720
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
menu = True
gender = True

display = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))

pygame.display.set_caption("Blazing Badge")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

warriorImage = pygame.image.load("warrior.png")
grassImage = pygame.image.load("grass.png")
playButton = pygame.image.load("play button.png")
durandal = pygame.image.load("durandal.png")
mainscreen = pygame.image.load("mainmenu.jpg")
logo = pygame.image.load("logo.png")

running = True
menu_viewed = False

def empty_screen():
    display.fill(white)

def text_objects(text, font, colour):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, colour)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


action = None

def game_menu():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        display.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font("The Fighter.otf", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Tech Demo", largeText, black)
        TextSurf = pygame.transform.rotate(TextSurf, 15)
        TextRect.center = ((displayWidth*0.68), (displayHeight*0.4))
        playpos = (((displayWidth/2)-100), (displayHeight)*0.7)
        durandalpos = (((displayWidth/2)-280), (displayHeight*0.2))
        display.blit(mainscreen, (0,0))
        display.blit(playButton, playpos)
        durandalresized = pygame.transform.scale(durandal, (561, 333))
        display.blit(durandalresized, durandalpos)
        display.blit(logo, ((displayWidth*0.2), (displayHeight*0.35)))
        display.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        print(click)
        print(mouse)


        if 580 < mouse[0] < 710 and 532 < mouse[1] < 674:
            if click[0] == 1:
                intro = False
                print("Start Game")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def character_creation():
    creation = True

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    gender_symbols = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("graphics\Character Creation", "Gender Symbols.png"))
    creation_background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("graphics\Character Creation", "creationbackground.jpg"))
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Choose your gender", pygame.font.Font("The Fighter.otf", 115), white)


    display.blit(creation_background, (0,0))
    display.blit(TextSurf, (((1280/2)-500), displayHeight*0.1))
    display.blit(gender_symbols,(340, (displayHeight*0.6)))
    pygame.display.update()

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    print(mouse)
    mcgender = "Null"
    creation = False
    gender = True

    while gender:
        print(click)
        print(mouse)
        if 365 < mouse[0] < 602 and 457 < mouse[1] < 702:
            if click[0] == 1:
                mcgender = "Female"
        elif 457 < mouse[1] < 702 and 677 < mouse[0] < 916:
            if click[0] == 1:
                mcgender = "Male"
        if mcgender != "Null":
            gender = False

    print(mcgender)

    display.blit(creation_background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

stone1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("graphics", "stone1.png"))

#Game Loop follows -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        print(event)

    if menu_viewed == False:
        game_menu()
        menu_viewed = True

    clear_screen = True

    gender = True

    character_creation()


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Can anyone provide some assistance? Running the following code, works will until the following section:

```py
while gender:
    print(click)
    print(mouse)
    if 365 < mouse[0] < 602 and 457 < mouse[1] < 702:
        if click[0] == 1:
            mcgender = "Female"
    elif 457 < mouse[1] < 702 and 677 < mouse[0] < 916:
        if click[0] == 1:
            mcgender = "Male"
    if mcgender != "Null":
        gender = False
```

No error code is produced, but the game window stops responding with no sign of restoring. The mouse readings continue in the terminal, but no response comes from the window. The only way to exit the program is be forcefully stopping the code from Pycharm.

Comment: You need to call the `pygame.event.get()` functions inside your loop for pygame to function correctly. Otherwise, it will just do nothing to the window, telling the OS that the programming is stuck.

Comment: you shouldn't use `while` loop which may run all time and loop `for event in pygame.event.get():`  may not get events from system so it can't get mouse position and button click . You should run loop which runs `for event in pygame.event.get():` and next check `gender` only once.

Comment: all `while`-loops should be similar - first they should use `for event in pygame.event.get():` to get events, next they should check mouse/key events only once (without any other `while`-loop), next should draw elements on screen and finally it should go back to the beginning and run all again. You should rather use `if gender:` instead of `while gender`

Comment: Changing the "while gender:" to "if gender == True:" worked. Thanks furas for the solution, and everyone else that volunteered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Are the mouse readings that continue actually changing when you move your mouse? It looks to me like you are not updating mouse position in your loop, so even if you mouse over an option pygame will think your mouse is still at the default spot it starts at.

Essentially, these lines should be inside your `while gender:` loop:

```
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
```

Comment: Moved the lines into the loop, but unfortunately didn't stop the game from crashing as soon as the game_menu() loop is stopped. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Does the program crash or is it still stuck in the  `while gender:` loop?  If the program crashes you will have an error message.

Comment: The Pygame window just stops responding, I can still see the mouse click and position going in the terminal, and clicking to select a gender doesn't print the gender like specified in the code. I am certain I am clicking in the right place.

Comment: @Hoog `get_pos()`, `get_pressed()` can't get new mouse position if program doesn't execute `pygame.event.get()` which gets all new events from system.